# Rails Admin vs Active Admin : Rails Admin generation tools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, rails-admin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails Admin vs. ActiveAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542075/rails-admin-vs-activeadmin)

I'm aware that there is already [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542075/rails-admin-vs-activeadmin) about this, but it was not so useful to me. I'm looking for an Admin generation tool for Rails and, apart from personal taste, I ca'nt decide whether use Rails Admin, Active Admin or other tools. HAve you had any experience with them? Can you suggest which you prefer, giving tech explanaitions and feedbacks?

Comment: This question adds nothing vs the question you referenced. That question is editable. Why not improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried Rails Admin, but Active Admin is pretty nice. 
Active Admin is flexible in the sense that it lets you customize the admin panel at great length, but requires a little bit of Rails (and Ruby) knowledge, and a few conventions here and there.

There is a nice video cast on Active Admin on this website [active admin @ railscast.com](http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin)

I personally prefer to manage objects directly from the front page (Authorization, Sessions, etc...), but all in all it depends what you intend to do for a website. For an e-commerce solution, having an admin panel is useful, but on the other hand I find it overkill for a blog ;).

hope it helps!