# Rails Admin vs Active Admin vs Typus vs Active Scaffold [2015]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, rails-admin, activescaffold, typus

which of the above would you recommend for a large e-commerce company? Although, most of the times, a simple CRUD interface suffices, there are at times, need for heavy customization. Also, speed is an important consideration.

I found a lot of articles, but all of them are very old and would like to know what is the best way to go about this today.

Comment: This question is very similar to [Rails Admin vs. ActiveAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542075/rails-admin-vs-activeadmin) and [Rails Admin vs Active Admin : Rails Admin generation tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526099/rails-admin-vs-active-admin-rails-admin-generation-tools) and probably should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I am used to use ActiveAdmin, it's really easy to customize as well it works really good for routine tasks, so for me it's better that Rails Admin. I haven't worked with 2 others so far.

Answer (score 0):

These are mature projects and old articles are still relevant, I have collected some on [our wiki](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki#alternatives).  I use Active Admin at a mid-size e-commerce company and am a project maintainer.  If want to use an [admin interface](https://ruby.libhunt.com/categories/22-admin-interface) Active Admin is a solid choice.